# RxJava 2 - andThen with Completable from Future?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have two completables that I need to call one after the other. I have this code:

```
public Completable getMyCompletable() {
    return getFirstCompletable().andThen(getSecondCompletable());
}

public Completable getFirstCompletable() {
    return Completable.fromFuture(getFirstFuture());
}

public Completable getSecondCompletable() {
    return Completable.fromFuture(getSecondFuture());
}
```

The second Future depends on the first Future being finished, otherwise it will fail. The problem (I think) is that when I call `getSecondCompletable()` and pass the result into `andThen()`, the second Future is created and begins to run, even though the second Completable hasn't been subscribed to and the first Future hasn't finished. This causes the second Future operation to fail, while the first Future operation succeeds shortly afterwards.

I'm migrating this code from RxJava 1 to RxJava 2. Originally the code used a FlatMap to run two `Single<Void>` operations consecutively. Because it used a FlatMap, the second Future was not created until the first one finished. How do I get this behavior in RxJava 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same pattern from RxJava 1.x but also defer the creation of the second future:

```
public Completable getSecondCompletable() {
    return Completable.defer(() -> Completable.fromFuture(getSecondFuture()));
}
```